# '>>=' ってなんて読むのでしょうか？

Tags: haskell

Haskellや圏論でおなじみの

```
(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

ですが,（上記はHaskellの型シグネチャーになります.）

口語ではなんて呼べば良いんでしょうか？

僕は勝手に"join fmap" とか読んでたんですが. 名称は存在するんでしょうか.

よろしくお願いします.

Comment: 正式な用語かどうかはわからないのでコメントで。オーム社からでている[プログラミングHaskell](http://estore.ohmsha.co.jp/titles/978427406781P)では、連結演算子、順序付け演算子（「そして」と読むと訳されている）と呼称してますね。ただ、モナドの説明前にでてくるし、索引でモナドの`>>=`と区別されている（型シグネチャーは同じ）ので便宜的なものかもしれません。

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pronunciation が参考になります。

私は“バインド”と呼んでいます。

Comment: このリンク素晴らしいです...!